# Another Community Moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

Stack Exchange sites are largely self-policed by the community, but we also need leaders from the site whose focus is to provide additional moderation support and site management as community moderators. It is important that the community moderators are a team of members, sharing the load of the site.

I am pleased to announce that another member has stepped up and generously volunteered to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: waiwai933]

waiwai933 joins [our existing moderators](https://english.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) in serving this community. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute. Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the time and effort they put in volunteering for the community.

Comment: How are moderators chosen? (Congrats, by the way!)

Comment: ah, we should have mentioned -- waiwai was the 5th place finisher in the http://english.stackexchange.com/election ; when we need more moderators between election cycles, we walk the election results in order of results, and offer the position to them. If they decline, we move on to the next candidate in the results.

Comment: *I saw that, which is why I'm asking, because obviously (well, obviously to me anyway), they haven't contacted the runner-up in the election, 'cause that was me.* - [Martha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1354548#1354548)

Comment: For the record, I *probably* would have declined, but it would have been nice to have actually been, like, *asked*.

Comment: We took [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1344543#1344543) as Martha declining.

Comment: @Rebecca: I can understand why you would do take the comment that way - but if (heaven forbid) something like this should happen again in the future, it would be wise to stick to offering it strictly to all candidates; that would be more tactful to the candidate(s) in question, and give the community confidence that the procedure was being followed strictly.

Answer (score 2):

Hi guys! I'm really happy to be here.

As I understand it, I've been brought in to (of course) moderate, but more specifically, to help ease the burden on the other mods. Additionally, I feel like as a starting mod move, I should help push the community along and help with the current Meta.English discussions about what questions we're going to accept.

*Based on feedback, I've retracted the proposed moderation policy and we'll leave it to further Meta.English discussion.*

Naturally, I welcome any disputes about specific actions I take as a mod here on meta.

Besides that,  I guess I should say that I'm excited about this, but I don't want to seem too overzealous about <s>punishing other people</s> moderating. :)

Comment: To be clear -- **we just want to spread the moderator load more evenly across all the moderators**. I would *not* say that our goal is to "push reforms" at this time, merely to make sure that nobody is getting burned out and that the moderator duties are fairly allocated.

Comment: We do *strongly urge* the community to get stricter about the quality of questions they will accept, of course, but that is something that has to be negotiated with the rest of the EL&U community.

Comment: @Jeff The last paragraph of [your post here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/is-elu-succeeding/1557#1557) seems to suggest something of the sort—although I agree "push reforms" might be a bit of an exaggeration, I was just trying to make it clear that I agree with the need for more aggressive moderation.

Comment: @Jeff And from Meta.English activity over the last few days (see a few of the new questions), I'm fairly certain the community does feel that we do need a push in this direction.

Comment: @Jeff But I've revised that second paragraph to phrase things better, anyway.

Comment: *"I feel that the community is in favor of a somewhat more aggressive moderation policy"* Not so fast. *Something* is needed, but it is by no means established that a simple "burn more stuff" is the right answer. (You'll notice most of the recent meta activity is from a few users, and most of the highly active people have not yet contributed: give them a chance before declaring consensus - or before implementing a drastic policy change - unless you want to inflame people more rather than calm them!)

Comment: @psmears Oh, I see. I'll take another look at those threads—I happen to have been really busy over the last few days, so I didn't give those my full scrutiny.